# Association only inserts to join table on create, but not on new then save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Verisons:**
Ruby 1.9.2p320
Rails 3.2.7

Using `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both my `users` and `shows` model. The association saves correctly with `create` but not with `new` then `save`. Also doesn't work with `build` and `save`. The problem is on `new` then `save` it does not insert anything into the `shows_users` join table.

**This Works:**

```
m = User.find_by_id(1)
m.shows.create()
```

**This does not work** (does not insert into `shows_users` when `saved`):

```
m = User.find_by_id(1)
d = m.shows.new()
d.save
```

**Please see screenshots from IRB below:**

Inserts into shows_users when using m.shows.create

[image]

Does not insert into shows_users when using m.shows.new and then save

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save User `m` as well, because you added the new show to this user.

```
m.save
```

writes to `shows_users`

or try

```
u=User.find(1)
s=Show.new
s.users << u
s.save
```

(btw: all tested in `rails console` of a real application.)

Comment: huh, when I do m.save it comes back false.

Comment: m.save
   (95.7ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (69.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('michaelcweiss@gmail.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (2.0ms)  rollback transaction
=> false

Comment: looks like a `validates :email, :uniqueness => true` that is triggered. Try it the other way round (HABTM is symmetrically). I add it to my answer.

Comment: Could you tell me what '<<' does? I see its assignment but not sure the difference from '='. Thanks

Comment: `<<` adds an item to an array. Here you add user `u` to the collection of users of `s`